# What is the definition, usage, and etymology of "flarn"?

Tags: meaning

I just [ran across the word "flarn"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/20875) as in, apparently, ["filth and flarn"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon).  What is the definition, usage, and etymology of "flarn"?  My poor google-foo yields nothing and I don't have an Oxford English dictionary.

Comment: Here are some [links to online references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2573/142322) that may help.

Comment: It may have begun as a nonce word used by Eddie Murphy in a stage rant he did about Bill Cosby. https://youtu.be/awvIeGWtr6I Link contains a certain amount of forthright language...

Comment: Not in the OED, nor on etymology online.

Comment: It's not a common word in the US.  Sounds to me like a made-up word for "excrement" or some such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Flarn) has a definition:

> A polite way to describe curse words.
>
> *"You can't say no filth flarn filth flarn filth"
>
>   "Have a coke and a smile, and shut the fuck up!"*

Given the hashtags on the entry, it seems likely that Eddie Murphy coined this word. The [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092948/quotes) lists these quotes (warning: language):

> *[Bill Cosby has called Eddie to complain about bad language in Eddie's act]*
>   Eddie Murphy: Now I can't have no 'curse' show, I mean I gotta throw in a few jokes in between the curses, I can't come out and go "Hello! Filth flar'n filth, motherfucker, dick, pussy, snot, and shit. Good night! Suck my dick!"

> Eddie Murphy: *[as Bill Cosby]* Yoouuu cannot say filth flarn filth flarn filth in front of people!
>   Eddie Murphy: And I said, "I never said no filth flarn filth! I don't know what you're talking about! I'm offended that you called! Fuck you!" And that's when Bill got raw on me!